# What happens when- A. Activity method is called from Runnable B. Multiple threads call Activity method simultaneously

Tags: java, android, multithreading

For the first part of the question, please consider the following pseudocode.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    .
    .
    // all necessary overridden methods
    .
    .
    Button.onClick() {
        (new Task()).run();
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        // do something here
    }

    public class Task extends Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

I am no expert in Java or any other programming language, so I'm unable to understand how the method `myMethod()` will be executed when the `Button` is clicked. Will `myMethod()`  execute inside the separate `Thread` of the `Runnable` as a separate "instance" of the method? Or will it execute inside the `UI Thread` since it is a part of my `Activity` class.

Now for the second part of the question, please consider the following pseudocode.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    .
    .
    // all necessary overridden methods
    .
    .
    Button.onClick() {
        (new TaskOne()).run();
        (new TaskTwo()).run();
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        // do something here
    }

    public class TaskOne extends Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                myMethod();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }
    public class TaskTwo extends Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                myMethod();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If `myMethod()` runs in the UI Thread due to it being a part of the `Activity`, what will happen when the method is called simultaneously by the two `Runnable` instances? I'm so confused. Will each `Runnable` instance execute a separate "instance" of the method, and if not, what will happen? Will each thread wait for each other's execution of `myMethod()`?

My confusion arises from trying to implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`. What if `onLoadFinished()` is called while `onLoadFinished()` is already running due to successive database updates?

I hope this post is appropriate to be on StackOverflow. If it is not, I'll promptly remove it. Thanks for any help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It will run in a separate thread (not UI Thread);

2) There will be a race condition. `myMethod()` will be called by both threads at the same time. To prevent possible errors you will have to make `myMethod()` `synchronized` or add `synchronized` block inside the method on certain objects.

All of these happens or course if you start new threads correctly :) now you call `run()` on `Runnable` which is not the right way. You should use `(new Thread(new TaskOne())).start();`.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. I have read often about `synchronized` methods and objects but never applied the concept in any project. Also thanks for pointing out my wrong usage of `Runnable`.

Comment: @DavidHeisnam hey, thank you, happy to be of any help. Please tell me if you have further questions later on. If you would like to know more about concurrency in java, I can recommend you this [free course](http://academy.javacodegeeks.com/course/java-concurrency-essentials/) that I personally once enjoyed (disclaimer: no affiliation with the company :) )

Comment: I'll be sure to let you know if I have a question that'll hopefully be good. (I'll be ending the THANKS chain by not saying thanks for that useful link on java concurrency..haha).

Comment: @DavidHeisnam in the meantime, if you don't mind accepting the answer... :)